# Excel sorting macro

Tags: sorting, macros

I want to make a macro that will sort the data alphabetically, add two lines between each group and after each of the groups create an average of that group's data in the first of the two empty rows.

[Initial data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6xuK.png)

[final data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfUCA.png)

I have created the first initial averaging step in a first attempt of macros and that has worked but it is the adding of extra lines where I have been having issues. I have not worked with making my own macros before or any form of coding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.